# Why are the composite and foreign keys not filling in the table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have built this database

[image]

and I wonder why are my foreign and composite keys filling the tables. I need some help

Comment: What do you mean with "filling the tables"?

Comment: i mean when i have my role id at 20 i thought it goes into staff_role as well

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean with "role id at 20"?

Comment: you know that the ids fill with every entry that's what I mean if I have 20 entries in my role table it means I will have 20 role_ids and I thought that it will fill the staff_role in my staff table as well

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize, you have following setting: Tables `A` (`id`) and `B` (`id`, `a_id`) with `B` referencing `A`.

Now if you add a record to `A`, there will not be an automatically generated record in `B` referencing the new record in `A`. So not every record in `A` has to be referenced by a record in `B`.

In fact, foreign keys work the other way around. If you insert a new record into `B`, there already has to be a record in `A`, which has the corresponding `id`. And if there is no such record in `A`, you will get an exception. This means, that every record in `B` needs to reference a record in `A`.

Anyways, also in the second case, there is no auto-generation of records.

Comment: the main problem I find is with the main volenterprise as I try to insert only info for my start and end date but I get an error saying that I 2 primary keys(basically two not nulls) and i need to insert data into them. How can i work around that .

Comment: You first have to fill the tables, that are referenced. So start `Role` and `Skill`. Continue with `Staff`, then `Enterprise` and `Provider`, then `Volunteer` and finally `VolEnterprise` and `VolSkill`. And btw: do NOT use capitals in your names, they will be converted to lower case (or you need to carry around double quotes everywhere). Use underscores instead of camel-case.

Comment: Do you think i should insert row numbers into vol_id and ent_id?

Comment: What row numbers? They are just references. And IDs should never carry any additional information. If you really need to order them somehow inside the table, use an extra column. But usually it should be enough to sort data on the fly while selecting it

Comment: the problem is psql doesnt let me insert data into start_date and end_date because my composite keys cant be null

Comment: So why would you want to insert only the dates? They do not have any meaning on their own.

Comment: Every table is full except the tables with composite keys and i cant really use them so that's why i am trying to get them fixed.

Comment: I cannot see what your problem really is. What inserts are you trying to do (give a code example), what error occurs and what is the reason/meaning of this insert?

Comment: I don't believe I'm using my relation tables correctly. what I need right now is to get an output for a volunteer that has more than 1 skills how can I do it.

Comment: I also don't think so.. you want to query something like `SELECT v.* FROM volunteer v WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vol_skill vs WHERE vs.vol_id = v.id) > 2`. But this starts to get another question, so open a new one. I am done here